# How to Install already created project of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a project which was developed on Laravel. I copied the project and pasted it in XAMPP's htdocs folder.

When I run the project from `localhost/LaravelProjectName`, it opens following screen:

[image: At: http://postimg.org/image/jkzjpe2yd/]

When I open `http://localhost/prg/public/`, it opens the login screen, but when I click on any link it opens the page with the following error message:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

I searched this on net but couldn't find anything related.

I have Install and update Composer in my destination folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `http://localhost/prg/public/index.php` 
 from this url all other route will work just fine.
 or use this code inthe .htaccess file in public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

this will enable you work from `http://localhost/prg`

Comment: It opens the the Login page, but after that each page redirects me to the following page : `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

Comment: You could have problem in your route file. goto app/storage/logs/laravel.log. and check the problem

Comment: #33 D:\xampp\htdocs\prg\bootstrap\compiled.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#35 {main} [] []

Comment: i think you have not properly define you route. perhap you define a post route instead of get. Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@showLoginPage'); is different from Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@showLoginPage');

Comment: I haven't edited anything in this project, I just copy the project and paste it into `xampp/htdocs` .The project was running successfully in other system

Comment: use http://localhost/prg/public/index.php to go to login page from there do same task that gave you the error, then send me the URL

Comment: It successfully opens the login page, but when i try to sign it using correct credentials, it takes me to the following error message - http://localhost/prg/public/error

Comment: ok i see now,  localhost/prg/public/error is your prob i noticed this too in Laravel, if the resultant url is  localhost/prg/public/index.php/error it would have worked. now try using this link  localhost/prg/public/index.php/  dont forget the last slash

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `DocumentRoot` of your `VirtualHost` to `/public` in your XAMPP/Apache configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myapp.localhost
  DocumentRoot "/full/path/to/laravel/install/public"
  <Directory "/full/path/to/laravel/install/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You would also want to update your `hosts` file with:

Linux/Mac: `/etc/hosts`

Windows: `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

```
127.0.0.1    myapp.localhost
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.. I don't have VirtualHost in XAMPP/APache..Kindly tell me where to edit ?

Comment: You'll need to look in the `conf` directory

Comment: My host file currently looks like this 

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost

Comment: kindly guide me the path of conf directory , I have seen this `<virtualhost>` thing in many places but couldn't find a way to edit this..

Answer (score 0):

you can enable debug mode by editing .env file. its locate in root folder.

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

or in the config/app.php

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG'),
```

this will gives you what is error rather than "Whoops, looks like something went wrong"

other that navigating to your public folder, you can launch laravel by navigating to root folder in cmd and type 'php artisan serve' it serves your website to localhost:8000 
(needs install composer.)

if not work, probably you need to run command 'composer update' to get dependencies.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0